# parts of page loaded with ajax dont work with functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this

```
    <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>Usage Left</td>
    <td>%</td>
    <td>Valid Until</td>
    <td>Days Left</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
</tr><!-- This is table head and is contained in multiple rows -->
```

I add/delete users with jquery but when i add a user instead of reloading the page i just append the row of newly added user to the table, so this newly added row delete doesnt work, however i can delete records after reloading the whole page again.

I checked the class name of added rows and they are correct and i am using

```
        $('.deleteThis').bind('click', function() {
});
```

function to delete records.

Comment: More code would be useful. I would also recommend using <th> for your table header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you need to use [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) instead of [`bind()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind) to bind an event handler to the newly added row